# Insert multiple records from xml

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I want bulk insert into a PostgreSQL database: backend code would create XML like

```
<items>
   <i dt="2014-08-01" name="vvv" count="12" />
   <i dt="2014-08-02" name="zzz" count="6" />
</items>
```

which I want to pass to a function and save all the values in one go.

But I'm stuck at `xpath`: each "column" seems to be an array of values, and I'm not sure how to insert them into a table then. Here's a test example:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_values (dt date, name varchar, count int);

WITH x AS (SELECT '
  <items>
    <i dt="2014-08-01" name="vvv" count="12" />
    <i dt="2014-08-02" name="zzz" count="6" />
    <i dt="2014-08-03" name="bbd" count="10" />
  </items>'::xml AS t
)
INSERT INTO temp_values
SELECT 
  xpath('/items/i/@dt', t),
  xpath('/items/i/@name', t),
  xpath('/items/i/@count', t)
FROM  x;
```

Now, in the end I want `temp_values` to have 3 records, as in the XML, but the table is empty.

If you comment out the "insert into" line, you'd see that the values are parsed correctly. It's just that it returns a single record where each column is an array, instead of returning multiple records.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and array indexing is the solution:

> unnest(array)  | expand an array to a set of rows

So the code would be

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_values (dt date, name varchar, count int) ON COMMIT DROP;

WITH x AS (SELECT '
  <items>
    <i dt="2014-08-01" name="vvv" count="12" />
    <i dt="2014-08-02" name="zzz" count="6" />
    <i dt="2014-08-03" name="bbd" count="10" />
  </items>'::xml AS t
)
INSERT INTO temp_values
SELECT 
  CAST(CAST((xpath('//@dt', node))[1] as varchar) as date),
  CAST((xpath('//@name', node))[1] as varchar),
  CAST(CAST((xpath('//@count', node))[1] as varchar) as int)
FROM (SELECT unnest(xpath('/items/i', t)) AS node FROM x) sub;

SELECT * FROM temp_values
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to delete some extra slashes before @:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_values (dt date, name varchar, count int) ON COMMIT DROP;

WITH x AS (SELECT '
  <items>
    <i dt="2014-08-01" name="vvv" count="12" />
    <i dt="2014-08-02" name="zzz" count="6" />
    <i dt="2014-08-03" name="bbd" count="10" />
  </items>'::xml AS t
)
INSERT INTO temp_values
SELECT 
  CAST(CAST((xpath('@dt', node))[1] as varchar) as date),
  CAST((xpath('@name', node))[1] as varchar),
  CAST(CAST((xpath('@count', node))[1] as varchar) as int)
FROM (SELECT unnest(xpath('/items/i', t)) AS node FROM x) sub;

SELECT * FROM temp_values
```